# Алгоритм удара по пешке (шашки)

Tags: javascript

Пишу шашки на node.js, в общем решил все моменты, осталось только 3 момента:
 это написать алгоритм удара по пешке, определение дамки и победа.

В общем стопорнулся на идее алгоритма, когда пешка бьет другую пешку.

**У меня есть общие координаты всей доски:**

```
        return {
        "white": {
            "P": 
                ["5.7","4.6","5.3","5.1",
                 "6.6","6.4","6.2","6.0",
                 "7.7","7.5","7.3","7.1"],
            "K": 
                [],
        },
        "black": {
            "P": 
                ["3.7","2.4","2.2","2.0",
                 "1.7","1.5","1.3","1.1",
                 "0.6","0.4","0.2","0.0"],
            "K": 
                [],
        }
    };
```

**отдельно координаты белых**

```
["5.7","4.6","5.3","5.1","6.6","6.4","6.2","6.0","7.7","7.5","7.3","7.1"]
```

**отдельно координаты черных**

```
["3.7","2.4","2.2","2.0","1.7","1.5","1.3","1.1","0.6","0.4","0.2","0.0"]
```

***Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли у кого идеи, по определению, какая пешка стоит под ударом?***

Comment: "...И никакие лекции не изменят этого соотношения сил, если каждый индивидуум в отдельности не будет постоянно тренироваться в шашк… то есть я хотел сказать — в шахматах…" (с) Ося Бендер.  
В шашках шашки называются шашками, а не пешками.  
И это, вы гуглить пробовали, ну там "алгоритм шашек", например?

Comment: А почему Вы не используете многомерный массив для координат?

Comment: Нет смотреть алгоритмы не пробовал. 

Касательно массива, честно говоря текущее мое решение очень удобное.

Comment: @NEPSTER 4234223: не уверен, что ваше решение удобное. Было бы оно удобным, проблем при определении кто кого бьёт не возникло бы. Я бы сделал двумерный массив, в каждой клетке либо белая/чёрная шашка, либо дамка, либо ничего. Белая шашка с координатами (x, y) стоит под ударом, если (1) (x+1, y+1) находится на доске и содержит чёрную шашку, а (x-1, y-1) тоже находится на доске и пусто, либо (2) (x-1, y+1) находится на доске и содержит чёрную шашку, а (x+1, y-1) тоже находится на доске и пусто. Симметрично для чёрных, плюс отдельная аналогичная проверка на дамки.